# Como puedo ordenar los datos de una archivo en linux conforme a la segunda columna?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, orderby

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo este archivo de texto el cual tiene nombre, apellidos, edad y mes de nacimiento.

Lo que me piden es esto: **usa solo una instrucción (con los comandos
apropiados y tuberías y/o redireccionamiento) para almacenar la lista de nombres
organizados alfabéticamente por su primer apellido.**

Intente este `cat p* | sort -k 2`

pero no sale...

lo que sale es esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se ordenan de forma alfabética por el primer apellido. Porque????

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si se pueden ordenar por mes.

**Ayudenme!!!**

Comment: probablemente debas indicar el delimitador en el `sort`. Sustituye las imágenes por texto para que podamos probarlo

Comment: Agregale `--debug` al sort para veas algun tipo de error. `sort -k2 --debug`, tambien  prueba con `-c` para verificar.